# batch: Iterate through directories and get directory names

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe

Given the following directory

```
D:\>dir D:\test1 /b
.dir1dot
.dir2dot
dir1
dir2
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

I want to iterate through all the directories from a given directory in **Windows 10**. Therefore I've built the following command

```
D:\>for /d %i in (D:\test1\*) do @echo %i
D:\test1\.dir1dot
D:\test1\.dir2dot
D:\test1\dir1
D:\test1\dir2
```

Now I want to obtain the names of the directories. That is:

```
.dir1dot
.dir2dot
dir1
dir2
```

I have tried executing the following but this is what happens:

```
D:\> for /d %i in (D:\test1\*) do @echo %~ni
ECHO is on.
ECHO is on.
dir1
dir2
```

Thus, the question is **How can I only display the names of the directories from a given directory?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use the `%~nxi` substitution to include the file extensions too since this gets the `.` prefix named folders. You'll still be assured no files are iterated since `FOR /D` deals with directories only.

   > ```
   > for /d %i in (D:\test1\*) do @echo %~nxi
   > .dir1dot
   > .dir2dot
   > dir1
   > dir2
   > ```

---

2. Furthermore, you can use a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop iterating the output of a [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command with the `/B` and `/AD` parameters to only get directories and no files, and to get the full path per each iteration including the `.` prefix named folders.

   #### Directory Names Only

   > ```
   > for /f "tokens=*" %F IN ('DIR D:\test1 /AD /B') do @echo %F
   > .dir1dot
   > .dir2dot
   > dir1
   > dir2
   > ```

   #### Full Path Directory Names

   > ```
   > for /f "tokens=*" %F IN ('DIR D:\test1 /AD /B') do @echo %~fF
   > D:\test1\.dir1dot
   > D:\test1\.dir2dot
   > D:\test1\dir1
   > D:\test1\dir2
   > ```

### Supporting Resources

- [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- `FOR /?`

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)

Answer (score 2):

PowerSHell: `(Get-ChildItem -directory).Name`

Alias/Abbv version: `(gci -ad).Name`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for /Directory` and `for /Recursive` in one loop `for /Directory for /Recursive`:

```
for /d /r "E:\your folder" %i in (*)do @echo\%~nxi
```